# How to fix Link different mongodb, How to fix nodmon: command not found error, How to fix connectToMongo is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend, nodemon

Problem: link different on your MongoDB.
Problem: nodemon: command not found.
Problem : TypeError: connectToMongo is not a function

Creating a MERN project. setting the frontend with reactjs and backend in nodejs with mongoDB.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: link different on your MongoDB
Solution: On connect page click on "Advanced Connection Options" below input box. Inside the advanced option tick on "Direct Connection". You should have similar uri to that used by harry.

Problem: nodemon: command not found
Solution: "npm install -g nodemon" then try nodemon. If still not working try "npx nodemon .\index.js"

Problem : TypeError: connectToMongo is not a function
Solution: write "connectToMongo;" in palce of "connectToMongo();"

Hope this helps
Enjoy.